# How to let user set time to run a task in google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine

My customer wants to set time (ex: Dec 13, 16:00 pm) to run a certain task.
I dont think cron job fits for it because customer dont know how to use google app engine SDK.
Is there any other way to do it?
Thanks

Comment: Built an interface for your client that they can use to create a task that executes at the desired time, as Andrei says.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a task and set the time when you want this task to be executed. From the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/overview-push):

> X-AppEngine-TaskETA, the target execution time of the task, specified
>   in milliseconds since January 1st 1970.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the task queue API: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/ or even the defer API:  https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/deferred

Answer (score 0):

If your customer is a user of your application, and there may be several users requesting tasks to be executed at different times, then you can save these requests to the datastore.  Create a cron job to run every hour (or however precise you need the timeframe) which checks the datastore to see if there are any tasks to run at that time - if so, run the proper script.

If this is just a one-time, or small number of tasks, you can do as Andrei suggested.